# Transformation of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say I have a differential equation,

$$
\dddot x = 4 \omega^2 (1 + \epsilon \cos (\Omega t)) \dot x-2 \epsilon \Omega \omega^2 \sin (\Omega t) x
$$

Here $\epsilon \ll 1$ and $\Omega \gg \omega$.

I want to tranform the above to this form,

$$
\dddot x = -\Omega_{eff}^2 \dot x
$$

Is there a way to transform such an equation. If yes can someone cite me some reference?

Comment: Do you want an aporoximation?

Comment: Yes that would work too.

Comment: You can use the method of harmonic balance or perturbation theory (e.g. regular perturbation theory, Poincaré-Lindstedt or multiple scales). Depending on the goal that you have you will have to apply one of the methods.

Comment: Yup. Originally I was trying LP. It's a very long and tedious process. So I was thinking if there is any clever trick in doing this.

Comment: @sbp : You wrote : $\epsilon<<1$ and $\Omega>>\omega$. This supposes that $\epsilon$ , $\Omega$ , $\omega$ are real (If not, the symbol $<$ is a non-sens). For $\epsilon\to 0$ the equations tend to $\dddot x = 4 \omega^2=-\Omega_{eff}^2 \dot x$. Thus $4 \omega^2=-\Omega_{eff}^2$ which implies $\omega$ or $\Omega$ complex. This is contradictory. So there is a mistake in the wording of the question. That is why I decided to delate my main answer (the contradiction in the wording was making inconsistent my calculus).